# Downloading point coordinate data from a website

Tags: qgis, point, coordinates, web

I would like to copy the red dots of the following web page:
https://www.inspectorulpadurii.ro/#/

to points in QGIS. The accuracy can be bad. I wanted to just place the points in QGIS with a background map for help.

But is there any way to download all these points?

(The project is about saving virgin forests.)

Comment: All the data is in https://www.inspectorulpadurii.ro/api/aviz/locations you will need to filter it.

Comment: Thank you very much! How did you know what the link to this data was? I was able to open this json with Excel, copy the information in 5 splits, put the rows in order and delete the points I don't need! Then I saved as tab-delimited txt and imported the txt as points in QGIS.

Comment: chrome>developer tools>network shows the locations.json file

Comment: I don't find it. Can you explain?